# CAGradientLayer gets overlayed on the tableviewcell's text in iOS 7 where as just works fine in iOS 8

Tags: ios, uitableview, cagradientlayer

In iOS 8 & in iOS7 :

[image]

[image]

I was working on the Clear like to do app by following a tutorial on the raywenderlich website. But I am stuck with a problem regarding with the CAGradientLayer. In this app the to do items are marked completed by striking of the text in the cell and inserting the green color layer to the cell.

I am inserting the layer of green color using **insertSublayerAtndex** method of CAGradientLayer.

There are two problems if I insert the green layer at index 0 it works in iOS 8 & it doesn'tin iOS 7. So I looked up stackoverflow & then tried to insert the green layer at index 1 for iOS 7 version of the app. But it overlays the text of the tableviewcell & the strike through layer as shown in the screenshot above.

Give me some hints to work around this problem so that the application will lookm exactly the same in both iOS7 & iOS8.